# How do i pass back http code 302 back to ajax from my php script

Tags: php

Here is my setup,

HTML page using jQuery AJAX to POST data to a php script. The php script in turn, calls a third party REST API. One of the response from REST API is 302 code.

My question is

1. How do i pass back the 302 return code to AJAX call and then let AJAX handle it?

To clarify this is my php script

```
$data = array(
    'id' => $id,
    'name' => $name
);


$postString = http_build_query($data, '', '&');

$ch = curl_init();

//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);

//close connection
curl_close($ch);
```

Now, $result has the response from the REST API, How do i send the 302 information back to my ajax script on html.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.header.php

Comment: success: function(data, textStatus, request){
        alert(request.getResponseHeader('some_header'));
   }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have already managed to detect the 302 in your PHP, then you can use the `header()` function to send a 302 status and a location header back to the client.

```
header("Location: http://example.com/foo/bar"); // 302 is the default for responses with a Location header
```

However, if you send a 302 response to an Ajax request then the browser will **transparently** follow it. There is no way to detect the 302 in your JavaScript.

The browser will then get the resource you are redirecting to.

You will then have one of two outcomes:

- The resource will be made available to JavaScript through the `responseXXX` properties
- You will have a Same Origin Policy security exception

If you want to display the resource as if a link was followed to it, then you need to give JavaScript the URL to visit (i.e. the URL you are being redirected to) in the response body. You could express it via JSON.

Then in the JS you need to extract that URL and set `location` to it.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP, try:

```
http_response_code(302);
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-response-code.php

Comment: only works with PHP >= 5.4; use header() in previous versions